# How to parse street address with Regex?

Tags: android, regex, street-address

I am working on a regex to parse full addresses by street number, street name, city, state, and zip code.

I came up with a pretty good regex that works for most cases, however, there are a couple scenarios where it fails. I need help with improving it. Here is what I have currently

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\\d-]{0,}[\\s-]{0,}[\\d/]+)[\\s]{0,}");
```

This works fine if the street addresses are formed nicely where the address starts with a street number that has no letters attached to it. For example :

- `123 Street Address, CA, 55555` **works fine**.
- However `123 4th Street Address, CA, 55555` will result in :

  ```
    1234 => street number
    th Street => street name
  ```

I have done a lot of research on parsing addresses and this solution I have come up with is just about the simplest solution I've found. Just need a little more tweaks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: In Europe we name streets like 'Britxon 2201' or '1945 victory 5' (5 is house number). Answering your question: you don't.

Comment: Because of the wide variance in address content and formatting, addresses aren't "regular"—an indispensable factor in using regular expressions to process information. This article elaborates: https://smartystreets.com/articles/regular-expressions-for-street-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't break down all street addresses into one regular expression. You're better off handling street addresses with multiple regular expressions to cover a wide range of scenarios e.g.

- 123 Stackoverflow Way
- 5000 5th Avenue
- 1 Hacker Way Building 5

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I added three different scenarios in addition to my regex and all is working fine. Thanks!